# PHP OCI8 module issue

Tags: php, linux, oci8

I get the below error when I perform php --version on linux env.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8 (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so (libclntsh.so.21.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_oci (/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_oci: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_oci.so (libclntsh.so.21.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.3.33 (cli) (built: Nov 16 2021 11:18:28) ( NTS )
```

I already installed the oracle-instantclient18.3-devel-18.3.0.0.0-3.x86_64.rpm and oracle-instantclient18.3-basic-18.3.0.0.0-3.x86_64.rpm modules.

but when I perform PHP --modules it is not showing oci8

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Is the oracle client library installed as well? https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/oow10/php_db/php_db.htm

Comment: yes it is installed

Comment: The error message shows PHP is looking for Oracle Instant Client 21c.  Did you install this version?  Using 18c isn't sufficient.

Comment: Hi @christopher jones I have installed Oracle Instant client 21 c and I got the same error

Comment: You *must* update your question with much more detail about what you installed and how you installed it.